# Does Android's Build class get impacted when we update the OS?

Tags: java, android, build

I'm implementing a Pseudo-Unique ID as shown below ATM and people say it won't be unique if user updates the OS. So does the [Build](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html) class get impacted on a OS update? If so, how?

```
public static String getPsuedoUniqueID() {

        String uniqueID = "35" +
                (Build.BOARD.length() % 10)
                + (Build.BRAND.length() % 10)
                + (Build.CPU_ABI.length() % 10)
                + (Build.DEVICE.length() % 10)
                + (Build.MANUFACTURER.length() % 10)
                + (Build.MODEL.length() % 10)
                + (Build.PRODUCT.length() % 10);


        String serial = null;
        try {
            serial = android.os.Build.class.getField("SERIAL").get(null).toString();


            return new UUID(uniqueID.hashCode(), serial.hashCode()).toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {

            serial = "helloWorld";
        }


        return new UUID(uniqueID.hashCode(), serial.hashCode()).toString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer from [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/26572/changing-android-os-build-serial)

In a scenario where a custom OS is implemented, that particular developer/team might follow a different approach to setting the values, (they might alter the values, e.g: for android.os.build.serial) So in a scenario where you decided to update to a custom OS there's a possibility that the Build class get impacted.

Answer (score 1):

It won't be unique at all.  For a given model of device, all of those lengths will be the same.  So every user with the same model will be the same.  At least-  its quite possible it will have collisions even before then.  Your idea is broken from the outset.  Use one of the existing ids in Android.  Or have them login and track by login.

Comment: If you were goi9ng to do that new version, then just use the serial.  What you're doing is pointless.

Comment: My question is how does the serial change when we update the OS? I mean Build.serial gives a hardware serial number, How does it get impacted from a OS update?

Comment: @GabeSechan, I wouldn't call it pointless, What I have done is increasing the possibility of keeping the key unique. (In a situation where it returns same serial for 2 devices, still I get the unique ID as a unique id since I have added the Build info)

Comment: @SajithKonara No, you really haven't. The odds of getting the same serial number, sorry of a bug giving the same serial number for each device of a given model (which did happen once) is a you won the lottery level odds. You just needlessly complicated things

Comment: @GabeSechan Trust me, I'm very lucky man :D So this could happen to me. Anyway thanks man. Really Appreciate it. And I found a solution in https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/26572/changing-android-os-build-serial to my original question.